# Laravel 5 and Socialite - How to extends fields

Tags: laravel-5

I use `Socialite` to allow users to log in with their facebook network account but I need the birthday date, how can I extends the Facebook provider?

The only solution comes in my mind was to update the `vendor` directory but with a composer update I will lost all the modification.

How can I extends it? Any idea?

Comment: Extend the base classes using extends

Comment: Any documentation about how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I managed how to extends, here the steps:

### Create your own class

Make sure that the new class will extends and implements all the interfaces required from socialite and add the stub method ( in my case I just copied the whole class and added new scopes ):

```
<?php namespace App\SocialLogin;

use Laravel\Socialite\Two\AbstractProvider;
use Laravel\Socialite\Two\ProviderInterface;
use Laravel\Socialite\Two\User;

class MyFacebookProvider extends AbstractProvider implements ProviderInterface {
}
```

### Add the new Provider

Edit your AppServiceProvider.php and int the boot method add the code to extends Socialite:

```
$socialite = $this->app->make('Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory');
        $socialite->extend(
            'facebook',
            function ($app) use ($socialite) {
                $config = $app['config']['services.facebook'];
                return $socialite->buildProvider(MyFacebookProvider::class, $config);
            }
        );
```

Make sure to add your own class name in the `buildProvider` method.

Comment: Amazing work and so little advice required to come up with the solution yourself!

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5 you can chain additional fields in your authentication methods like so:

```
public function redirectToProvider()
{
    return Socialize::with('facebook')->fields([
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'gender', 'birthday'
    ])->scopes([
        'email', 'user_birthday'
    ])->redirect();
}

 public function handleProviderCallback(){
    $user = Socialite::with('facebook')->fields([
        'name', 'email', 'gender', 'verified', 'first_name', 'last_name'
    ])->user();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation:
It can be done like this:

```
public function LoginToFb()
{
    if(!config("services.facebook")) {
       abort('404'); 
    }
    return $this->socialite->with("facebook")->scopes(['scope1', 'scope2'])->redirect();
}
```

read more here:
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#social-authentication

Comment: I don't understand what the scopes actually do here.  I know scopes are a way to extend queries, but I don't see the connection with Socialite.  Can you explain what happens?  The docs give the same example you did.

Comment: @mtpultz maybe a bit late (lol) but the `scopes` refers to the extra permissions that you need the user to accept in order to access driver specific data (like `manage_pages` in Facebook).